# Trouble on android linux in Jenkins

Tags: android, api, sdk, jenkins, android-sdk-tools

meet face to face with trouble that :

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 1, sorry!

properties in my build gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
```

What it can be?

Answer (score 0):

versionCode in your code example is 1, the exception says API level 1 is not supported...I have the impression that "versionCode" represents the API level. What happens if you increase the versionCode - Value?

Comment: no versionCode is not anything to do with API level it is Application version code

Comment: no, it isn't do anything. problem very strange, when i run this build with the same properties on another machine/node, this problem doesn't appear. what to do?!

Answer (score 0):

am not sure about your environment or tool setup, just make sure that your jenkins build is configued to build using gradle/gradle based build tool (only they will parse build.gradle file and generate a Manifest with proper fields) or if u r using some other build tool update the AndroidManifest with appropriate api level values

Comment: as i say, if i execute the same build with the same properties on another node, there are no problems(

Comment: then it must be environment issue, cross check sdk tools, build tools repos, gradle version used. try to do a step by step compiltaion from commandline as jenkin would do, and make sure all the steps are completed normally

Comment: but nodes are the same with same versions of sdk and other tools

Comment: can it be that before buid was ecuting another emulator and it don't shut down? s

Comment: I am not familiar with roboelectric but the error message doesnt look like because of multiple emulator. Instead a error message says it is incompatible with api version, either could be a low api emulator or application compiled for older api.

Comment: how can i add api platforms using terminal? which code for update to api level 19?